# Convert combined date variable into seperate items

Tags: php, date

I have a dynamically generated variable in php called $date which looks like....

```
12-02-1972
23-03-1985
18-12-1992
6-04-2001
```

I would like to take this $date string and split it into its separate components so that I end up with for example....

```
$day
$month
$year
```

What would be the best way of doing this, some sort of regex to separate out the digits from the dashes?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PHP function [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php);

```
$date = "12-02-1972";
$date = explode('-', $date);
$date[0]; // this is your day
$date[1]; // this is your month
$date[2]; // this is your year
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', '12-02-1972');
```

Comment: +1: this answer is way nicer than accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Y** for year, **m** for months, **d** for days

So your example:

```
$year  = $date->format('Y');
$month = $date->format('m');
$day   = $date->format('d');
```

Format how ever you need it

Answer (score 2):

```
sscanf('12-02-1972', "%d-%d-%d", $day, $month, $year);
# now you have variables $day, $month and $year filled with values
```

<sup>p.s. return values are integers, not string</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
$day = date($date, 'd');
$month = date($date, 'm');
$year = date($date, 'Y');
```